# Google My Business Profile APIs Location Patch request has the different structure then uploading via UI

Tags: oracle-adf, google-my-business-api

Google My business when we update an location's hours the csv has the data in the format via UI
For example:- `storecode | Sunday hours| Monday hours | Tuesday hours`
[UI format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znRFC.png)

and the API accepts the format which is different then UI
[API format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpZik.png)
For example:-

can anyone tell me there is way to upload (UI format)csv  into the endpoint
https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/locations/locationId?updateMask=regularHours&validateOnly=true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For patching location data, the GBP API currently only accepts JSON.

In the case of the opening hours, the `TimePeriod` format you found already is the only way (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#timeperiod).